# Fade out video/audio with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, filter, ffmpeg, fadeout

i'm trying to simply fade out both video and audio of an input.mp4.
The video lasts 00:29:59 (1799 sec) and i want to fade out the last sec.
I'm using this command (it should just fadeout the video):

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fade=t=out:st=1798:d=1 output.mp4`

but it always give me the same error:

```
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.
[aac @ 0000000002605b60] Qavg: 2430.591
[aac @ 0000000002605b60] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The file i was trying to edit was corrupted, with other files the filter works well :)

Answer (score 5):

Well if you were trying to also fade out the audio you would I believe need to incorporate the `afade` filter. You can accomplish both using a complex filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
        "[0:v]fade=t=out:st=1798:d=1[v]; \
         [0:a]afade=t=out:st=1798:d=1[a]" \
     -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

add `'-max_muxing_queue_size 999'` to your ffmpeg command that is:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -max_muxing_queue_size 999 -vf fade=t=out:st=1798:d=1 output.mp4`

haven't tried this command myself but I've encounter myself with same error and the flag solved the problem. See also [ffmpeg ticket](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/issues/86)

Comment: why 999? Is this arbitrary?  I used 1024 and it worked as well.